# Centering floated elements in full-width div

Tags: css, css-float

I'm working on a product catalog page, and the group of images needs to be centered but I have yet to find a way to do so, since they're all floated in a div that's a 100% in width.

I'm looking for a way to center those images horizontally without losing the flexibility of their floating properties.

Here's a link to the catalog on the website: http://internetvolk.de/katalog/

Comment: Please include the relative css and html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using `display: inline-block;` istead of floating and add `text-align: center` to their parent container)

Answer (score 2):

Augment with the following rules:

```css
#katalog {
    text-align: center;
}
```

and

```
.imageLink {
    /** float: left; <-- REMOVE! */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: This method works, but would it be possible to have the last row left-aligned, but the DIV itself centered. I hope you know what I mean :)

Comment: You would abandon this method, and instead give the container div a fixed width and `margin: 0 auto;` as suggested by matpol.

Answer (score 0):

if you give #katalog a width - calculate this from the number of images and their margins. e.g.

```
#katalog{
width: 960px; /*just an example*/
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#katalog {
    margin: 10px auto 0;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-width: 940px;
    min-width: 810px;
}
```

Use `max-height` and `min-height` to keep flexibility, I'm defining a `max-width` to keep it centered in all screens by adding `margin: 0 auto;`